# CSS Rendering differently on server than local

Tags: css, iis

I have this annoying CSS rendering issue that I am not sure what is causing it.

on my local copy everything looks that way I want it. When I deploy it to the server IIS.

there is one minor very minor DIV that is not rendering the way I want it or the same is what the local copy renders.

In this case, there is a padding on top and bottom of the div when there should not be. It looks fine in the local.

I tried setting the X-AU in the header but that did not help.

It is only rending that one div differently. all of the other elements looks fine. This is really strange.

Comment: Are you looking at it in the same browser?

Comment: Let me inspect your code ..... Ah true there is no code to inspect

Comment: try to clear your browser cache on local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to disable IIS static content compression?
I already had issues with minified jquery and css on servers running IIS and I had to change it to non-minified versions of it.

Comment: YEs. After I posted the question I checked the bundle thing. Some how the asp.net bundler was giving a different result.  I moved all the css to the html page instead of using the bundle feature. I still don't know where the problem lies but was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if on your local you are running the site using SSL? I had a similar issue. I was running the site within VS 2013 and local IIS over SSL and on the live site, I was not. Fix was to configure https bindings on the live site and this fixed the issue.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, the answer should be given in full after your query has been answered.